# Getting SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs) because of sending too many?

Tags: python, smtp

I'm using Python to send mass emails. It seems that I send too many and too fast that I am getting SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs) errors.

I used 

`server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code you send mass emails?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was sending to empty recepients.